# Allow to load insecure scripts for one specific website?

Tags: google-chrome, security

Often when I browse SE, a YouTube video is being embedded. Unfortunatelly, my Chrome doesn't like videos on a text based website, so it shows me the "whoopsie" icon where I have to click to load the website again with Flash Play enabled.

[image]

This answer already dealt with this problem, but only has a solution for the whole Chrome experience.

**Is there a way to let a single website always load insecure content?**

Comment: This doesn't sound like insecure content, it sounds like it is simply non-text content.

Comment: Everything can be seen except the video, it's a blank space (big as the video should be). When I let it load, it loads.

Comment: If this is truly YouTube content then Chrome should not need a flash player because the web browser should support all YouTube videos natively. Try uninstalling Adobe Flash for all web browsers and try again.

Comment: Example: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59668/what-are-the-lyrics-to-the-children-from-game-of-thrones-s04e10 --- and even if... please stay on-topic. :)